# Know widget is installed or not?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to whether my widget is installed by user or not  , do you know any way to find out user installed my widget or not , I am know that there is no specific or documented way to do this .

Do you have any suggestion ?

thanks

**if when user installed my widget , I get some codes or any where I will be notifed (like OnUpDate) , I can save that in my shared prefs .**

Do you know this code or way ?

Comment: Maybe via sending a parameter to your online service the first time your widget connects to the net?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `getInstalledProviders` for getting list of all installed app widgets.as:

```
AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager= AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> installed = mAppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders();
//YOUR APP WIDGET INFO HERE
AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
```

Comment: this will show full list of widgets , that whether installed or not .

Comment: ok you are getting full list of widget and now search for you app widget if installed or not

Comment: Oh u want to know user added ur widget on screen or not right?

Answer (score 4):

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
```

The allWidgetIds2 array will contain instances of your Widget in question which have been added to your home screen

Comment: this worked for me and should be the approved answer.